# SocketError handling in Prolog

Tags: sockets, exception, swi-prolog

I'm a bit unfamiliar with the mechanics of error recovery in prolog, so I apologize in advance if the question seems stupid.
I am looking for a way to properly handle SocketError in swi-prolog. So far I have only found the following snippet:

```
setup_call_catcher_cleanup(tcp_socket(Socket),
                           tcp_connect(Socket, Host:Port),
                           exception(_),
                           tcp_close_socket(Socket)).
```

Whenever a connection is refused, it raises the appropriate exception and performs the cleanup action, closing the socket.

Problem is, i want to embed this in a predicate  `test_socket/3` that sets a status code whenever a connection gets refused and I cannot seem to find a way to do so. I tried doing:

```
test_socket(Host, Port, Status) :-
     setup_call_catcher_cleanup(tcp_socket(Socket),
                                tcp_connect(Socket, Host:Port),
                                exception(_),
                                (tcp_close_socket(Socket), Status = 1).
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: The purpose of the argument `Cleanup` is to perform some cleanup action, and then to continue, as if this cleanup has not happened. That is, the exception goes further up and `Status = 1` is superfluous. The construct is not made to do everything. But probably a `catch/3` above all of this, is what you want.

Comment: ... and: Most of the time `setup_call_cleanup/3` is used, the version with `catcher` is rather for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the argument `Cleanup` is to perform some cleanup action, and then to continue, as if this cleanup has not happened. That is, the exception goes further up and `Status = 1` is superfluous. The construct is not made to do everything. But probably a `catch/3` above all of this, is what you want.
                    – false